# SlickGrid grid sizing with display: table

Tags: javascript, html, css, slickgrid

I have a box of a static size. Within the box, I have a slickgrid instance and some temporary content that shows up at the bottom. I'd like the grid's vertical size to flow nicely so that all of the temporary content shows up at the bottom without resizing the parent box.

I have accomplished this using `display: table;` and `display: table-row;` on the divs.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/f7aTX/): Toggle the content before adding the grid to see what I want it to do. Click "Add Grid" to initialize the grid and cause the issue.

SlickGrid does not appear to size itself correctly when the container is using `display: table;`. It gets way too big horizontally and seems to grow in size when calling `grid.resizeCanvas()`.

If you remove the table display from `#table` and `#tallRow`, the grid sizes itself correctly. However, toggling the content does not properly shrink the grid vertically. I could size the container manually in JS before calling `grid.resizeCanvas()`, but the table/table-row solution was very elegant and I'd like to keep it.

Any ideas?

HTML

```
<button id="add" onclick="addGrid()">Add Grid</button><button onclick="toggle()">Toggle Content</button>
<div id="box">
    <div id="table">
        <div id="tallRow">
            <div id="grid"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tempRow">
            <div id="test">Some content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
}

#box {
    background: #666;
    width: 350px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

#tallRow {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}

#grid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #777;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#tempRow {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
function toggle() {
    var el = document.getElementById('tempRow');
    el.style.display = el.style.display == 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    grid.resizeCanvas();
}

var grid;
var columns = [
    {id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title"}
];

var options = {
    fullWidthRows: true,
    forceFitColumns: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false
};

function addGrid() {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        data[i] = {
            title: "Task " + i
        };
    }

    grid = new Slick.Grid("#grid", data, columns, options);
    document.getElementById('add').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use : `table-layout:fixed;` to  `<table>` or `display:table;` element so it won't shrink/expand anymore if a width is specified . **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f7aTX/1/)**

```
#table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Comment: There is no way to fix height, table element will keep extend as much as its needed to hold content.

Comment: That does get it much closer though. I've been playing with manually adjusting the height of `#tempRow` and that is pretty messy, especially since `#tempRow` actually contains an Angular directive in my application.